# I have trouble dealing with multiple check box, i don't know what is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I trying to make multiple check boxes but i keep having this problem. 
whenever

i made three check boxes but when i click the second or the third check box, only the first check box is selected, i keep changing and checking my code for an hour, but i have no idea what is problem :( :(

here is my code.

css

```
.squaredThree {
    width: 20px;    
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.squaredThree label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredThree label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#one input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

#two input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}


#three input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="one">
<div class="squaredThree one">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree"></label>
</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
<div class="squaredThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree1" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree"></label>
</div>
</div>

<div id="three">
<div class="squaredThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **but when i click the second or the third check box, only the first check box is selected**. Provide a jsfiddle for that.

Answer (score 2):

Because your label has `for` attribute of first checkbox. So you must be use unique id for inputs and set `for` attribute of label to related input.

You can use this:

```
<div id="one">
    <div class="squaredThree one">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree1" name="check" />
        <label for="squaredThree1"></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="two">
    <div class="squaredThree">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree2" name="check" />
        <label for="squaredThree2"></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="three">
    <div class="squaredThree">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree3" name="check" />
        <label for="squaredThree3"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OH Thank you so so much for helping me!!

Answer (score 1):

Use seperate `id` for the three inputs.In your code you are using same `id` for the third input.Also you are using the id of the first input in `for` attribute of the last label. Set `for` attribute of label as the id of the related  input

```css
.squaredThree {
    width: 20px;    
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.squaredThree label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredThree label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

#one input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

#two input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}


#three input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 
<div id="one">
<div class="squaredThree one">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree"></label>
</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
<div class="squaredThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree1" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree1"></label>
</div>
</div>

<div id="three">
<div class="squaredThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree2" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree2"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OH Thank you so so much for helping me! it works very well now!

Answer (score 0):

The above html code have some issues, like:

. You are using the same `ID's` for more then one element.

. When there are multiple checkboxes having same name, then name must be an array to hold multiple values like `check[]`.

. Your label has `for` attribute only of first checkbox.

Comment: OH Thank you so so much for helping me!